# How to to handle form that is called in jquery post request

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a comment system in which there is a from with hidden comment-id input, the comment system is back-ended by php and i have use jquery post request to bring comments in html pages. every thing is working fine except if i try to handle the form in comments through jquery it does not give any response.

**comment system in php**

```
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):?>
  <div class="comment-container">

    <div class="comment"><?php if(!empty($row['comment'])){echo $row['comment'];}else{echo 'None.';} ?></p></div>

    <form name="comment_delete" method="post">
    <input name="remove" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    <input value="Delete" type="submit" class="comment-delete" />
   </form>

  </div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

**jquery to handle comments.**

```
function get_comments(){
$.post('../comment.php', {value1:url1, value2:comment}, function(data)
   {
   $('#comments').html(data);
});

$('form[name=comment_delete]').submit(function(){
            alert('hi')
});
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to handle this form via jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: "every thing is working fine except if i try to handle the form in comments through jquery it does not give any response". Can you kindly explain this in more detail. I am sorry, i failed to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="comment_delete" method="post" onsubmit="return get_comments()">
```